# The largest polydivisible number

Tags: number-theory

I'm reading a [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0374275653) book that says that the largest [polydivisible number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydivisible_number#How_many_polydivisible_numbers_are_there.3F) is the number 3,608,528,850,368,400,786,036,725

I looked around but I couldn't find a proof that shows this result.

Can anyone tell us why this is the biggest polydivisble number?

Thanks!

Comment: Note: I'm not even sure what number theory is so if my tag is wrong please change it ;)

Comment: The wiki page says that the number you write is the only number with 25digits. If you accept that, then you can easily prove that the number is the largest.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** all credits are due to the original [author](http://www.blog.republicofmath.com/author/garyernestdavis/)

[This article may be useful](http://www.blog.republicofmath.com/the-number-3608528850368400786036725/).

> Ben Vitale (@BenVitale) announced that 3608528850368400786036725 is  a
>   25 digit number with the property that  each number formed by its
>   first n digits is divisible by n, for n from 1 through 25.
>
> How could we find similar numbers, and could there be a larger number
>   than 3608528850368400786036725 with this property? (which we will call
>   the Vitale property)
>
> The numbers with 2 digits having the Vitale property are just the even
>   numbers between 10 and 98.
>
> We will investigate this issue using Mathematica®, so here’s our list
>   of such 2 digit numbers generated in Mathematica®:
>
> **vitaleproperty[2] = Range[10, 99, 2]**
>
> {10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,
>
> 52,54,56,58,60,62,64,66,68,70,72,74,76,78,80,82,84,86,88,90,92,94,96,98}
>
> How about numbers with 3 digits with the Vitale property?
>
> They have to be obtained from even numbers by adding a digit to the
>   left, and must be divisible by 3.
>
> Here’s how Mathematica® can generate all the numbers obtained by
>   appending a digit from a given number:
>
> **adddigits[n_] := Table[FromDigits[Append[IntegerDigits[n], d]], {d, 0,
>   9}]**
>
> For example, here’s what we get by applying the adddigits function to
>   248:
>
> **adddigits[248]**
>
> {2480, 2481, 2482, 2483, 2484, 2485, 2486, 2487, 2488, 2489}
>
> To obtain 3 digit numbers with the Vitale property we have to append a
>   digit to even numbers, and check which resulting 3 digit numbers are
>   divisible by 3:
>
> **Cases[Flatten[Map[adddigits, vitaleproperty[2]]], x_ /; Mod[x, 3] ==
>   0]**
>
> {102,105,108,120,123,126,129,141,144,147,162,165,168,180,183,186,189,201,
>
> 204,207,222,225,228,240,243,246,249,261,264,267,282,285,288,300,303,
>
> 306,309,321,324,327,342,345,348,360,363,366,369,381,384,387,402,405,
>
> 408,420,423,426,429,441,444,447,462,465,468,480,483,486,489,501,504,
>
> 507,522,525,528,540,543,546,549,561,564,567,582,585,588,600,603,606,
>
> 609,621,624,627,642,645,648,660,663,666,669,681,684,687,702,705,708,
>
> 720,723,726,729,741,744,747,762,765,768,780,783,786,789,801,804,807,
>
> 822,825,828,840,843,846,849,861,864,867,882,885,888,900,903,906,909,
>
> 921,924,927,942,945,948,960,963,966,969,981,984,987}
>
> These are the 3 digit numbers divisible by 3, who’s first 2 digits
>   are divisible by 2.
>
> This suggests how we can recursively build n digit numbers with the
>   Vitale property, from n-1 digit numbers with the Vitale property:
>
> **vitaleproperty[n_] := vitaleproperty[n] = Cases[Flatten[Map[adddigits,
>   vitaleproperty[n – 1]]], x_ /; Mod[x, n] == 0]**
>
> For example:
>
> **vitaleproperty[4]**
>
> yields:
>
> {1020,1024,1028,1052,1056,1080,1084,1088,1200,1204,1208,1232,1236,1260,1264,
>
> 1268,1292,1296,1412,1416,1440,1444,1448,1472,1476,1620,1624,1628,1652,1656,
>
> 1680,1684,1688,1800,1804,1808,1832,1836,1860,1864,1868,1892,1896,2012,2016,
>
> 2040,2044,2048,2072,2076,2220,2224,2228,2252,2256,2280,2284,2288,2400,
>
> 2404,2408,2432,2436,2460,2464,2468,2492,2496,2612,2616,2640,2644,2648,2672,
>
> 2676,2820,2824,2828,2852,2856,2880,2884,2888,3000,3004,3008,3032,3036,
>
> 3060,3064,3068,3092,3096,3212,3216,3240,3244,3248,3272,3276,3420,3424,3428,
>
> 3452,3456,3480,3484,3488,3600,3604,3608,3632,3636,3660,3664,3668,3692,3696,
>
> 3812,3816,3840,3844,3848,3872,3876,4020,4024,4028,4052,4056,4080,4084,
>
> 4088,4200,4204,4208,4232,4236,4260,4264,4268,4292,4296,4412,4416,4440,
>
> 4444,4448,4472,4476,4620,4624,4628,4652,4656,4680,4684,4688,4800,4804,
>
> 4808,4832,4836,4860,4864,4868,4892,4896,5012,5016,5040,5044,5048,5072,
>
> 5076,5220,5224,5228,5252,5256,5280,5284,5288,5400,5404,5408,5432,5436,
>
> 5460,5464,5468,5492,5496,5612,5616,5640,5644,5648,5672,5676,5820,5824,5828,
>
> 5852,5856,5880,5884,5888,6000,6004,6008,6032,6036,6060,6064,6068,6092,
>
> 6096,6212,6216,6240,6244,6248,6272,6276,6420,6424,6428,6452,6456,6480,6484,
>
> 6488,6600,6604,6608,6632,6636,6660,6664,6668,6692,6696,6812,6816,6840,
>
> 6844,6848,6872,6876,7020,7024,7028,7052,7056,7080,7084,7088,7200,7204,
>
> 7208,7232,7236,7260,7264,7268,7292,7296,7412,7416,7440,7444,7448,7472,7476,
>
> 7620,7624,7628,7652,7656,7680,7684,7688,7800,7804,7808,7832,7836,7860,
>
> 7864,7868,7892,7896,8012,8016,8040,8044,8048,8072,8076,8220,8224,8228,
>
> 8252,8256,8280,8284,8288,8400,8404,8408,8432,8436,8460,8464,8468,8492,
>
> 8496,8612,8616,8640,8644,8648,8672,8676,8820,8824,8828,8852,8856,8880,
>
> 8884,8888,9000,9004,9008,9032,9036,9060,9064,9068,9092,9096,9212,9216,
>
> 9240,9244,9248,9272,9276,9420,9424,9428,9452,9456,9480,9484,9488,9600,
>
> 9604,9608,9632,9636,9660,9664,9668,9692,9696,9812,9816,9840,9844,9848,9872,9876}
>
> The size of the collection of n-digit numbers with the Vitale property
>   grows with n for a while, but then begins to decrease:
>
> **T = Table[{n, Length[vitaleproperty[n]]}, {n, 2, 15}]**
>
> {{2,45},{3,150},{4,375},{5,750},{6,1200},{7,1713},{8,2227},{9,2492},{10,2492},{11,2225},{12,2041},{13,1575},{14,1132},{15,770}}
>
> A plot shows this initials increase and then decrease quite markedly:
>
> **ListPlot[T, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}]**
>
> [image: Vitali_numbers]
>
> So, lets’s calculate, and plot, the number of n-digit numbers with the
>   Vitale property versus n for n from 2 through 26:
>
> **T = Table[{n, Length[vitaleproperty[n]]}, {n, 2, 26}]**
>
> {{2,45},{3,150},{4,375},{5,750},{6,1200},{7,1713},{8,2227},{9,2492},{10,2492},{11,2225},{12,2041},{13,1575},{14,1132},{15,770},{16,571},{17,335},{18,180},{19,90},{20,44},{21,18},{22,12},{23,6},{24,3},{25,1},{26,0}}
>
> **ListPlot[T, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}]**
>
> [image: vitali_numbers_2]
>
> So we see that there is exactly one 25 digit number with the Vitale
>   property – the venerable 3608528850368400786036725 – and that
>   appending any of the digits 0 through 9 to this number does not result
>   in a 26 digit number that is divisible by 26. This means that
>   3608528850368400786036725 is the LARGEST number with the Vitale
>   property.
>
> Kudos to Ben Vitale for finding it!